# Set .JAR default action to run with Java?

Tags: java

Currently, with my install of Ubuntu 10.10, Java JARs by default open with `file-roller`.  How can I set it so that when I double-click a JAR in Nautilus, it opens with Sun Java 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on any .jar files and select properties. Click on the 'Open With' tab (usually the 4th tab). select Sun 'Java 6 Runtime'(if you are using sun Java otherwise select appropriate Java from the list). And click close to save the settings.

[image]

Comment: on Ubuntu 22.04, there is no "close". there is "select" - it opens with Java, but doesn't save this setting.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 22.04 solution:

1. select the jar
2. hit *ctrl+I* to enter the properties
3. go to *Open With* tab
4. select Java
5. click *Set as Default*